# Internet Explorer 7 compatibility with YouTube iframe API?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I wonder if anyone can answer this question. I use the Youtube API to request onReady() and OnStateChange() events and using an IFRAME to embed the video.

Though I come across an issue with IE7 where the events are not firing. I understand there is a callback compatibility issue with IE browsers IE 7 and below.

Is there a work around this? Maybe using the flash API version?

if so could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Requirements):

> The end user must be using a browser that supports the HTML5
>   postMessage feature. Most modern browsers support postMessage, though
>   Internet Explorer 7 does not support it.

Comment: I thought that only was an issue when using the html5 iframe API not the flash?

Comment: It applies whenever you're using the iframe API. If you want an alternative that works with IE 7, see https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

Answer (score 0):

I still have to test this out in my environment, but this is a possible postMessage() backfill: https://github.com/joshfraser/postmessage . Here's the article it came from: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2010/01/15/backwards-compatible-postmessage/