# Adding an onTimeout callback

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is more of a design question that I would love to talk to you about.

We have a Javascript SDK that clients can interface our API with (think stripe.js).  We want to add functionality so that the client is notified when a timeout has occurred (e.g. something happens down the chain and the request takes over 30 seconds).

There are couple of options we can go down:

- Add another argument that takes in a function that will be called when an `XMLHTTPRequest` has timed out:

```js
    App.tokenize({
      // params to send
    }, function (response) {
      // SUCCESS OR FAIL RESPONSE
    }, function() {
      // CALLED WHEN REQUEST TAKES OVER 30 SECONDS
    });
```

- Consolidate response to the single callback:

```js
    App.tokenize({
      // params to send
    }, function (response) {
      // SUCCESS, FAIL, OR TIMEOUT RESPONSE
    });
```

We believe that the single callback should be for round-trip HTTP requests with status codes. If the request times out on the client, we won't get a `HTTP 408 TIMED OUT` response.

What makes sense when you are interfacing with a Javascript SDK like this? Have you found any examples of SDKs handling client timeouts?  Any insight into this would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't vote for promises...especially if the client's have IE < 7 customers. I would use globally registered callbacks. Yeah, they're ugly. Google does it though https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started or instead of multiple callbacks modify the instance's state with other properies like `responseState` or whatever.

Comment: *What makes sense...* sounds like you're asking for opinion, which is not really on-topic for SO. *Have you found any examples...* sounds like you're looking for an off-site resource, which is also off-topic for SO. Honestly, either one of the provided options, or the idea of Promises as @jantimon suggests, are all fine, depending on whether those are consistent with the remainder of your API...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - It seems okay after a quick review of [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) ... provided answers invite sharing experiences over opinions and explain the how and why.

Comment: @Daniel_L google stopped supporting IE7 a long time ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300295/internet-explorer-7-compatibility-with-youtube-iframe-api

Comment: @Roberto, the key problems with the question are: *every answer is equally valid* and *your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers*.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness of (or lack of) a question.  When interfacing with other client libraries, have you encountered a special callback handler for timed out requests? If so, do you have an example of the docs so I can review the design? If you have not, do you handle timeouts separately on your end (e.g. after X seconds, send another request)?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Promisses can be [polyfilled for older browsers](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) and are [supported by the modern ones](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises). If you are a using [angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) or [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) you can use their built in promise features.

Your code might look like this:

```
function getToken() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
       reject('TIMED OUT');
     }, 3000);
     yourAjaxCall(function ajaxCompleted(result) {
       clearTimeout(timeout);
       resolve(result);
     });
  });
}
```

For your clients it would be very convenient to consume your api in a way they are already used to:

```
  getToken()
    .then(function(token) {
      console.log('got the token', token); 
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('something went wrong:', err);
    });
```

And with the new ES7 `await` feature (requires an es7 transpiler like typescript or babel) they would be able to use your API without any callback.

```
async function logThatToken() {
  await token = getToken();
  console.log(token);
}
```

Comment: We'll look into promises. Ideally, a vanilla JS solution would be ideal since our clients might not have jQuery or angular installed.  Also polyfilling this feature for a callback that might be called < 1% of the time seems like a little too much.  Definitely will explore it though.  Thanks!

Comment: For modern browser this IS vanilla js and the pollyfill is extremely lightweight < 1kb gzipped. And you are future ready.